# How to determine, whether to use machine learning algorithms or data mining technique for a given scenario?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have been reading so many articles on Machine Learning and Data mining from the past few weeks. Articles like the difference between ML and DM, similarities, etc. etc. But I still have one question, it may look like a silly question,

***How to determine, when should we use ML algorithms and when should we use DM?***

Because I have performed some practicals of DM using weka on Time Series Analysis(future population prediction, sales prediction), text mining using R/python, etc. Same can be done using ML algorithms also, like future population prediction using Linear regression.

So how to determine, that, for a given problem ML is best suitable or Dm is best suitable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the closest thing to the quite arbitrary and meaningless separation of ML and DM is **unsupervised methods vs. supervised learning**.

Choose ML if you have training data for your target function.

Choose DM when you need to explore your data.